# ReactBootstrap popover dismiss on click outside

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap

ReactBootstrap provides a popover control. I would like this to be dismissed on clicking outside the popover in a similar way to how modals work (it just dismisses by default clicking out of the box).

Is there a way to do this using ReactBootstrap or do I need to custom code something?

JSfiddle of a popover: http://jsfiddle.net/226cwe4e/

```
React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <ReactBootstrap.OverlayTrigger trigger="click" placement="bottom" overlay={<ReactBootstrap.Popover title="Popover bottom"><strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> Check this info.</ReactBootstrap.Popover>}>
        <ReactBootstrap.Button bsStyle="default">Holy guacamole!</ReactBootstrap.Button>
      </ReactBootstrap.OverlayTrigger>;
    }
});
```

Comment: have you tried `trigger={["focus", "click"]}`

Comment: have a look [here](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/67ef392268ca5cdc7139a6ad8c22430851a8782b/src/OverlayTrigger.jsx#L29)

Comment: @knowbody that gets really close but click and focus, means it immediately closes when you click it the first time (see http://jsfiddle.net/862fht00/), just focus means it works how I want except clicking on the link again doesn't close it, I think this is the closest to the behaviour I want so I will just go with that.

Comment: @knowbody actually focus also means clicking on something in the popover dismisses it, so you cant have a button in there for example

Comment: yeah I've realised that. that as close as I can help. I think the hover over option is the closest to what you want. check their github repo, I think I've seen a opened ticket on this issue

Comment: also just found this http://jsfiddle.net/spicyj/q6hj7/

Comment: @knowbody interesting that's done from scratch without ReactBootstrap. Ill see if I can find the issue in the backlog and +1 it :) thanks for your help

Comment: For those interested the issue for this in ReactBootstrap is https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/233

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work for you:

```js
const Hello = () => (
  <ReactBootstrap.OverlayTrigger 
    trigger="focus" 
    placement="bottom" 
    overlay={
      <ReactBootstrap.Popover title="Popover bottom">
        <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> Check this info.   
      </ReactBootstrap.Popover>
    }
  >
    <ReactBootstrap.Button bsStyle="default">Holy guacamole!</ReactBootstrap.Button>
  </ReactBootstrap.OverlayTrigger>
);

ReactDOM.render(<Hello />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0g6ybry8/)

Comment: "It's inadvisable to use "hover" or "focus" triggers for popovers, because they have poor accessibility from keyboard and on mobile devices."

It would be good to highlight what you changed and why it would resolve the question, rather than just pasting code.

Answer (score 65):

No you don't need any custom code. Just include `rootClose` prop and this will do for you. Its in the react bootstrap official documentation https://react-bootstrap.netlify.com/components/overlays/#overlays-api

```
<OverlayTrigger trigger='click' rootClose>
  ....
</OverlayTrigger>
```

Comment: Thank you!! I was looking so hard for that

Comment: this docs is misleading, i didnt think the overlay trigger is the same as overlay and inherit props

Answer (score 4):

For React Bootstrap 4.4 it's necessary to add a `onHide` function alongside `rootClose`, also these properties are for `Overlay` Component (not `OverlayTrigger`).

Here is an example:

```
function Example() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const target = useRef(null);

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setShow(!show);
  };

  return (
    <div ref={ref}>
      <Button onClick={handleClick} ref={target}>Holy guacamole!</Button>

      <Overlay
        show={show}
        target={target.current}
        placement="bottom"
        rootClose
        onHide={() => setShow(false)}
      >
        <Popover id="popover-contained">
          <Popover.Title as="h3">Popover bottom</Popover.Title>
          <Popover.Content>
            <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> Check this info.
          </Popover.Content>
        </Popover>
      </Overlay>
    </div>
  );
}

render(<Example />);
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @makuno 's answer. In case you wish the popover to be kept open on clicks inside the popover and dismissed on clicks outside you can use the following

```
<OverlayTrigger trigger='click' rootClose>
    <div onClick={e => {
        e.stopPropagation(); 
        e.preventDefault(); 
        e.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }}>
        Click me, I won't dismiss the popover
    </div>  
....
</OverlayTrigger>
```

The key thing to note here would be the `e.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation()` statement

Comment: This is especially important if you are creating a popover within a React-Bootstrap Modal.

Answer (score 1):

None of the above worked for me. This worked for me. I had to pass `rootCloseEvent="mousedown"` along with `rootClose={true}`

```
<OverlayTrigger
          rootClose={true}
          rootCloseEvent="mousedown"
          trigger="click"
          placement="left"
          overlay={
            <div className="delete--team cursor-pointer">
              some text
            </div>
          }
        >
```

Comment: In rootCloseEvent I added rootCloseEvent='click' and it started to close itself on a trigger element click and when you click on an outside area of a popover.