# Close reactjs bootstrap-popover with button on click outside

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

Hi have a bootstrap popover on with button inside it . I want to close the popover on click of the button as well as on loss of focus what can I do ?
Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g0a0pu0L/2/)

```jsx
var Hello = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <ReactBootstrap.OverlayTrigger trigger="focus" placement="right" overlay={<ReactBootstrap.Popover title="Popover bottom"><strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> Check this info<ReactBootstrap.Button bsStyle='primary'>Save</ReactBootstrap.Button> </ReactBootstrap.Popover>}>
        <ReactBootstrap.Button bsStyle="default">Holy guacamole!</ReactBootstrap.Button>
      </ReactBootstrap.OverlayTrigger>
    );
  }
});

React.render(<Hello />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

I tried focus it will close popover on click inside the popover .

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28935314/reactbootstrap-popover-dismiss-on-click-outside/28950765#28950765

Comment: @knowbody this is not duplicate .. please read question once again ..

Comment: ok, sorry. Partly agree though. check the github issue page mentioned in the link above. also very similar interaction has been implemented react-bootstrap dropdown menu. just a matter of tweaking. I try to send JSFiddle whenever I find some more time

Comment: this might help you https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/155 also this might be something interesting for you too http://www.leecarmichael.com/bootstrapx-clickover/examples.html - not react though

Comment: @knowbody Yes I am looking at this as well as solution on close all other popover on document click